# Solve the system of equations with exponential term.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve this system of equations. I know the answer but I am struggling with the working. I need to solve for $m$ and $s^2$ in terms of all the other parameters. The system of equations is shown below

\begin{align}
e^{(m+\frac{1}{2}s^2)}=l_1+l_2+(r-\frac{1}{2}\nu_1^2)t+(r-\frac{1}{2}\nu_2^2)t\qquad(1)\\
e^{(2m+s^2)}(e^{s^2}-1)=\nu_1^2t+\nu_2^2t+2h\qquad(2)
\end{align}

I have noticed that the first term of the LHS of $(2)$ is the square of LHS $(1)$. Calling the RHS of $(1)$ and $(2)$ as $a$ and $b$ respectively, we have

\begin{align}
e^{(2m+x)}&=a^2\\
a^2(e^x-1)&=b
\end{align} where $s^{2}=x$ (say).

I have got to the point where,

\begin{align}
m = 2\log a - \frac12 \log(b + a^2)\\
s^2 = \log(b+a^2) - 2\log a
\end{align}

but struggling when doing the algebra, as in when replacing $a$ and $b$ by their corresponding terms in $(1)$ and $(2)$.

I would very much appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Writing  $$e^{m+\frac{1}{2}s^2}=a$$ and $$e^{2m+s^2}(e^{s^2}-1)=b$$ taking the logarithm on both sides and both equations we get
$$m+\frac{1}{2}s^2=\ln(a)$$
$$2m+s^2+\ln(e^{s^2}-1)=\ln(b)$$
multiplying the fist equation by $$-2$$ and adding both we get
$$\ln(e^{s^2}-1)=\ln(b)-2\ln(a)$$ from here you will get $$s$$
And then good luck!